# Echo PHP in Javascript?

Tags: php, echo

I have see numerous examples of this but none give the answer how to change 'buynow' with php echo. 
htlm code

```
 <button id="pn4" class="paynow-button"
        data-business="example@gmail.com"
        data-item_name="PayNow Plugin"
        data-amount="150"
        data-quantity="1"
        data-currency_code="USD">
        <span class="paynow-label">Click to Buy </span>
        <span class="paynow-price"><sub>$</sub>150</span>
</button>
```

Js code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#pn4').paynow({
            type: 'buynow', 
            style: 'double',
            tooltip: 'Click to checkout with PayPal!'
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have added this code but no result.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#pn4').paynow({
            type: '<?php echo $detail['my_name']; ?>', 
            style: 'double',
            tooltip: 'Click to checkout with PayPal!'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What is the resulting generated HTML?

Comment: Welcome to SO, your question is a little lacking in details. How are you defining what is the variable `$detail`? What you've shown would work perfectly, but we'd need to know how you're getting that value and what else you might want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "
<script>
   $('.paypal').ClassyPaypal({
type: '".$detail."',
});

</script>"; 
?>
```

The reason why you should do that, is that php loads before your javascript, so you cannot echo a value into a script that hasn't loaded yet

__Edited:

Try to encode your value

```
<?php echo json_encode($detail); ?>
```

Using json_encode() requires:

```
PHP 5.2.0 or greater
$detail encoded as UTF-8 (or US-ASCII, of course)
```

Since UTF-8 supports full Unicode, it should be safe to convert on the fly.

Comment: That is functionally no different to what user2692541 already had. The value will be loaded into the javascript before being sent to the browser, so it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your php is returning a empty value. Your script should work perfectly. You can also try using AJAX.

Also try it like this

```
"<?php echo $php_var; ?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

In General, if your web server supports PHP, your own example should work. PHP and JS only have some differences in how they interpret/print a string. For example: if your PHP variable contains a newline, this newline is printed in your JavaScript string. But JavaScript does not accept newlines in a string, you will need to escape those. Also, keep in mind you will have to escape single quotes as well. The following example would be a little better:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#pn4').paynow({
            type: '<?php echo str_replace(array("'", "\n"), array("\'", "\\\n"), $detail['my_name']); ?>', 
            style: 'double',
            tooltip: 'Click to checkout with PayPal!'
        });
    });
</script>
```

But even better would be to take `json_encode()` as Ralph suggested. This function will translate the PHP string to a correct JavaScript string. Be sure not to include the quotes in JavaScript. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#pn4').paynow({
            type: <?php echo json_encode($detail['my_name']); ?>, 
            style: 'double',
            tooltip: 'Click to checkout with PayPal!'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Be sure to check if `$detail['my_name']` is a string in this case. Otherwise it may break the JavaScript code for the PayPal button!